# Setting connection parameters in iOS-Corebluetooth Framework

Tags: ios

According to the Core Bluetooth Framework Reference there is an option argument on the CBCentralManager.connectPeripheral method, but there is no documentation that describes it other than to mention that its "A dictionary to customize the behavior of the connection.".

I'm assuming that this is how the caller would specify the initial connection interval and slave latency. Please provide the dictionary details(i.e key of the dictionary).

Please suggest me, how to give the key and value for the connection parameters dictionary(mentioned above).

Thanks and Regards
-Ibrahim Sulaiman

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not allow to set custom connection parameters. Instead it chooses appropriate values in respect to the iOS BLE guidelines.

See last paragraph here: https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/22400867--HOW-TO-Maximize-throughput-with-BLE-modules

See chapter 3.6 here: https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The [options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Peripheral_Connection_Options) are in the documentation.

They are -

- CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey
- CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey
- CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnNotificationKey

and they control the creation of alerts prompting the user to launch your app when the corresponding Bluetooth events occur and you haven't specified Bluetooth background mode.

You cannot change the connection interval from an iOS app, only the peripheral can request a change. Refer to the last paragraph on [this page](https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/22400867--HOW-TO-Maximize-throughput-with-BLE-modules)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response

Comment: We already aware of this points. But, we are interest to know about the dictionary key and value pairs.

Comment: These are the dictionary keys and the values are true/false.  There are no options for this dictionary